# How do I get my angular app on my hosting to view as a web page?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, web-applications, azure-devops, web-deployment

So I finished the Tour of Heroes tutorial.  I understand it and can alter and have fun and what not. Got a git repository from Visual Studio Team Services for the app.  Now here is where I'm lost I just want to build web based apps for now.  How do I get the app on to my hosting to display as a website.  I can't seem to find any tutorials (or once that I can understand) online for this.

If anyone can help with this or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking: "How do I get the app on to my hosting to display as a website"..what? Like web hosting or is this some sort of microsoft thing I am not familiar with?

Comment: All you have to do is copy your html, css, js to your web host. Make sure you replace index.html or whatever is the main html with your angular html. This is to just getting started. There are lot of techniques to deploy and create angular application distributions. You can checkout gulp/grunt angular yeoman app creators.

Comment: I'm looking into gulp/grunt right thank you.  The index asks for some files that are only found in the node_modules. I appreciate this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to these articles to deploy angular app ([part 1](https://moopoo.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/use-npm-and-gulp-build-tasks-to-support-continuous-deployment-with-vsts-and-azure-for-an-angularjs-app/) and [part 2](https://moopoo.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/deploy-an-angular-app-to-azure-app-services-web-app-with-vsts-continuous-integration-builds/)).
Simple steps:

1. Use NPM and gulp build tasks to build and package your app
2. Deploy package to azure or IIS.

There is IIS Web App Deploy task in [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp), so you can install this extension and deploy packaged app to IIS if you want to deploy app to IIS.

Comment: Thank you I have already gotten a Windows Azure account and I'm in the process of following their instructions.  I thought it was as simple as putting up a static html page but it is far from it.

Comment: @byrondiggs The articles have the detail steps, what's your problem now?

Comment: @byrondiggs You can provide the details of your issues.

Comment: This was the right answer I just didn't know how to "build" the app.  I was finished the Tour of Heroes tutorial and assumed I was finished. They don't have a "how to build your app ready for deployment" part.  I found a good tutorial here... http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/12/24/creating-an-angular-2-build.html 
Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider probably gave you a FTP access to a root directory for your website.
Upload the project over there and make sure there is an index.html file there, that pulls all the relevant JS files into place.